# Checking how often strings from a txt file are associated in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a text file with some simple data:

```
elephant  dog
elephant  cat
elephant  dog
cat  dog
cat  elephant
```

And I need to check how often the words are associated with each other and output it (elephant & dog 2 times, elephant and cat 2 times, cat & dog 1 time). How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How would you go about doing it by hand? Once you understand that translating to Ruby should be easy.

Comment: If you're curious about the downvotes, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. If it's still not clear  not clear after reading that why it got downvoted, make a comment here, as it will help us improve the documentation.

Comment: I don't quite see how it breaks the rules, but I guess I'll take y'all's words for it. Maybe I didn't "relate it to other people."

Comment: "Maybe I didn't "relate it to other people."  -- No, the reason is that you put no effort of your own into trying to solve the actual problem you are faced with.

Comment: Actually, yes I did -- I just had nothing of value to show for it.

Comment: I'll take this to MSO, but note that this question meets: a) All the criteria on the first page and b) All the criteria under the first level of detail for "on topic". It's only when you get to the link about what questions to avoid does this issue of "trying" comes up, which is problematic to assess for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments aside and with the understanding that this question and answer may be deleted ;-), I'll offer up the following:

```
pairs = string.lines.collect {|l| l.chomp.split('  ').sort.join(',')}  # eliminate ordering diffs
pairs.uniq.each {|p| puts "#{p} = #{pairs.count(p)}"}
```

See http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/a47c8

I'm offering this because I think the criteria and downvoting process "needs work".

Answer (score 0):

```
s = <<_
elephant  dog
elephant  cat
elephant  dog
cat  dog
cat  elephant
_

s.scan(/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/).map(&:sort).inject(Hash.new(0)){|h, pair| h[pair]+= 1; h}
```

Result:

```
{
  [
    "dog",
    "elephant"
  ] => 2,
  [
    "cat",
    "elephant"
  ] => 2,
  [
    "cat",
    "dog"
  ] => 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = <<-end
elephant  dog
elephant  cat
elephant  dog
cat  dog
cat  elephant
end

ar = s.split("\n").map{|i| i.split}
# => [["elephant", "dog"],
#     ["elephant", "cat"],
#     ["elephant", "dog"],
#     ["cat", "dog"],
#     ["cat", "elephant"]]
ar.each_with_object({}){|i,h| h[i.sort] = ar.count{|j| i == j or i == j.reverse}}
# => {["dog", "elephant"]=>2, ["cat", "elephant"]=>2, ["cat", "dog"]=>1}
```